# how to get docker to include wwwroot static content aspnet core

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to get include a swagger.json file into my docker image. 
I am using aspnet core 2.2 
When I run my app locally it picks up the swagger.json file sitting in wwwroot.
when I create my docker image and run it, swagger starts but won't find the .json so it just errors out. I am very new to docker. 
I should note it also didn't find a test.gif file I dropped into wwwroot either.
Am I missing something in the docker file? 
I definitely want to include the .json file in my image.

dockerfile:

```
        FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443

    FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["myApp.Api/myApp.Api.csproj", "myApp.Api/"]
    COPY ["myApp.logic/myApp.logic.csproj", "myApp.logic/"]
    COPY ["myApp.Models/myApp.Models.csproj", "myApp.Models/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "myApp.Api/myApp.Api.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/myApp.Api"
    RUN dotnet build "myApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "myApp.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.Api.dll"]
```

csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <UserSecretsId></UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="4.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\myApp.logic\myApp.logic.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\swagger.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

docker command

```
docker run -it -p 5001:80 myapp:latest
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem on ASP.NET Core 2.1 but only with the Docker images. Windows 10 includes the `wwwroot` folder as expected without any modifications. But on docker it doesn't work. Tried different include directives e.g. `<Folder Include="wwwroot/" />`, `<Content Include="wwwroot/" />` and others without success. The `wwwroot` folder exists in the Docker image, but after publishing it's missing in the publish target directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the solution was renaming subfolders and files to lowercase because paths are case sensitive with the Docker image.